# Speed up performance of nested function computations

Tags: performance-tuning, parallelization

I'm trying to create a model for intensive computations for a homomorphic encryption scheme. The core of my problems is a series of function calls

```
h00=Function[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[Mod[(#1[[2]]-#1[[1]][[1]])*(#2[[2]]-#2[[1]][[1]]),q],2],wrdLen+1]];

hi0=Function[Table[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[Mod[#1[[1]]*(#2[[1]][[1]]-#2[[2]])-#1[[2]]*#2[[1]],q],2][[u]],wrdLen+1],{u,2,n+1}]];

h0j=Function[Table[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[Mod[#1[[1]][[1]]*#2[[1]],q],2][[i]],wrdLen+1],{i,2,n+1}]];

hij=Function[Table[PadLeft[IntegerDigits[Table[Mod[#1[[1]][[i]]*#2[[1]][[j]],q],{i,2,n+1},{j,2,n+1}],2][[u]][[v]],wrdLen+1],{u,1,n},{v,1,n}]];
hijτ=Function[Join[{Catenate[{{h00[#1,#2]},h0j[#1,#2]}]},Transpose[Catenate[{{hi0[#1,#2]},Transpose[hij[#1,#2]]}]]]];

SHMult=Function[Catenate[{{Mod[Sum[hijτ[#1,#2][[i]][[j]][[wrdLen+2-τ]]*a[[1]][[i]][[j]][[τ]],{i,1,n+1},{j,1,n+1},{τ,1,wrdLen+1}],q]},{Mod[Sum[hijτ[#1,#2][[i]][[j]][[wrdLen+2-τ]]*k[[1]][[i]][[j]][[τ]],{i,1,n+1},{j,1,n+1},{τ,1,wrdLen+1}],q]}}]];
```

Function `SHMult` calls all previous functions and depending on the number of simulations this might be repeated a lot of times. Basically, what it does is that it creates a big square matrix `hijτ` where `h00` produces the element `{0, 0}`, `hi0` produces all other elements of the first column, `h0j` produces all other elements of the first row, and `hij` produces a submatrix with all other elements of the matrix.

Not also that the indices for `i, j, τ` might be also large; for example a 256 x 256 matrix of 32-bit values. As a first step I tried to use `Compile` instead of `Function` for all these functions with the parallelization option given, but I got errors. Also I tried `ParallelTable` instead of `Table`, but I got an error saying that `ParallelTable` can't be used in a nested environment.

Is there any way to optimize this somehow?

Comment: What is `wrdLen`? How did you try to call compile?

Comment: It is a constant defined before calling the functions. I just didn't define it to simplify the question. For compile I set Compile[{x,y}...,Option] and replaced the #1, #2 in the function definitions with x and y.